# Selenium WebDriver C# -- continue when exception thrown

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, exception, webdriver

I want to check for the presence of a number of elements on the page and if any were not present I want to see a list of custom error messages telling me which ones were not present.

At the moment I have:

Test case:

```
[Test]
public void CheckAllElementsArePresent()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(Results.CheckFirstElement());
    Assert.IsTrue(Results.CheckSecondElement());
    Assert.IsTrue(Results.CheckThirdElement());
}
```

Framework:

```
public static bool CheckFirstElement()
{
    var results = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("firstElementSelector']"));

    if (results == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Cannot find first element");
    }

    var attr = results.GetAttribute("id");
    if (attr == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Cannot find first element");
    }

    if (attr.Contains("someTextIWantToFind"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will work, however, the test will fail if any of these fails. I need a way to continue running the test and then spit out any errors at the end of the test, eg: "Cannot find the first element", "Cannot find the third element" etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class that will hold methods for your needs

```
public static class MakeSure
{
    private static List<string> errorsFound = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> getErrors() { return errorsFound; }

    public void ElementIsNotNull(IWebElement element, string elementName)
    {
        if(element == null)
        {
           errorsFound.Add("Cannot find element " + elementName +".");
        }
    }

    public void ElementHasAttribute(IWebElement element, string elementName, string attribute)
    {
        if(element.GetAttribute(attribute) == null)
        {
            errorsFound.Add("Cannot find " + attribute + " attribute of the element."); 
        }
    }

    public void ElementContaisText(IWebElement element, string elementName, string attribute, string text)
    {
        if(!element.GetAttribute(attribute).Text.Contains(text))
        {
            errorsFound.Add("Cannot find the text " + text +" in " + elementName +" element"); 
        }
    }
}
```

and you can call them from your Test Case to "MakeSure" your element has a specific attribute,is not null etc. You can create more overloads so you won't have to put "ID" to "attribute" everytime, like so:

```
public void ElementHasAttribute(IWebElement element, string elementName)
{
    ElementHasAttribute(element, elementName, "id");
}
```

So everytime you want your attribute to be "id", you just call the overload method. You can pretty much do anything following the above example and change the code/methods to your needs.

You can also modify your Results class to do the following

```
public void CheckFirstElement()
{
    IWebElement firstElement;
    MakeSure.ElementIsNotNull(firstElement, "first element");
    MakeSure.ElementHasAttribute(firstElement, "first element", "id");
    MakeSure.ElementContaisText(firstElement, "first element", "id", "Text to validate.");
}
```

So all you will have to do in your test is:

```
Results.CheckFirstElement();
```

Comment: This looks great, I'll try and implement it - thank you!

Comment: No problem! My pleasure. If you have any question about the implementation, just drop a question and I will answer it whenever I can

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is modify the methods to return an error string:

```
public static string CheckFirstElement()
{
    var results = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("firstElementSelector']"));

    if (results == null)
    {
        return "Cannot find first element";
    }

    var attr = results.GetAttribute("id");
    if (attr == null)
    {
        return "Cannot find id attribute of first element";
    }

    if (!attr.Contains("someTextIWantToFind"))
    {
        return "Cannot find the text in first element";
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then collect any errors found in the main test:

```
[Test]
public void CheckAllElementsArePresent()
{
    var errors = new List<string>();
    var error = Results.CheckFirstElement();
    if(error != null)
        errors.Add(error);
    error = Results.CheckSecondElement();
    if(error != null)
        errors.Add(error);
    error = Results.CheckThirdElement();
    if(error != null)
        errors.Add(error);

    if(errors.Any())
    {
        //Output to console
        var errorString = string.Join(";", errors);
        Console.Writeline(errorString);
        //Fail the test
        Assert.Fail(errorString);
    }

}
```

This is just one way. You can get a bit more sophisticated and return a class as a result with a `boolean` and an `ErrorMessage` property if you want to get fancy.